# No sound and RTP failure when playing back file from Asterisk Server

Tags: asterisk, sip, rtp

I've recently installed my first Asterisk on AWS EC2 instance and experienced some minor issue, currently phones are not recieving the hang up instruction and also no sound when playing back a file from the server.

I think the issue is to do with the public and private IP issue of the server instance, so I have a public ip of x.x.x.x and a private ip of y.y.y.y on the instance , the phones register to the server on x.x.x.x and can dial extensions and now with some NAT alterations I can hear and talk from phone to phone bu they do not hang up at end of calls, also if playing back a file from the server there is no sound and no hang up at the end of the call.

Ive tried it with the firewall compelte off and ALL TRAFFIC ALL PORTS open on the instance so i dont think its a forewall or NAT issue as ironed these  out, I think its to do witht he internal and external IP's being different or perhaps the RTP protocal port on the instance not being set somewhere

the handsets show that they are connecting but then the RTP protocal fails ( and it shows the y.y.y.y iternal ip as below when i expected it to show the public IP x.x.x.x

```
16/4/2019 15:30:06 [NOTICE] PHN: TPL: Socket 364 idle/connect timeout
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [ERROR ] PHN: SIP: transaction_timeout udp: 1001331 (32000)
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [ERROR ] PHN: SIP: transport error: 1001331 -> udp:y.y.y.y:5060
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [NOTICE] PHN: SIP: Add dirty host: udp:y.y.y.y:5060 (0 sec)
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [NOTICE] PHN: SIP: final transport error: 1001331 -> udp:y.y.y.y:5060
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [ERROR ] PHN: SIP: transport error 1001331: generating fake 599
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [NOTICE] MEDIA: MediaIpc::rtpClose: RP72
16/4/2019 15:30:10 [NOTICE] MEDIA: MediaIpc::rtpClose: RC72
16/4/2019 15:30:12 [WARN  ] PHN: SIP: process_registrar_packet: 401 needs 128 bit nonce
16/4/2019 15:30:12 [NOTICE] PHN: SIP: process auth:Match challenge for user=WB001, realm=asterisk
16/4/2019 15:30:12 [NOTICE] PHN: RTP: set_destination RP73 adr=y.y.y.y:19684
16/4/2019 15:30:12 [WARN  ] MEDIA: CallStats: 2156890680 not found
```

The server shows the following log..

```
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Executing [200@LocalSets:1] Answer("SIP/WB001-00000015", "") in new stack
-- Executing [200@LocalSets:2] Playback("SIP/WB001-00000015", "hello-world") in new stack
-- <SIP/WB001-00000015> Playing 'hello-world.gsm' (language 'en')
-- Executing [200@LocalSets:3] Hangup("SIP/WB001-00000015", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (LocalSets, 200, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/WB001-00000015'
[Apr 16 15:30:45] WARNING[13228]: chan_sip.c:4119 retrans_pkt: 
Retransmission timeout reached on transmission f2e6b55c11ce-zqpp4q4dbedu for seqno 2 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 31998ms with no response
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
 -- Executing [101@LocalSets:1] Dial("SIP/WB001-00000016", "SIP/WB002") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Called SIP/WB002
-- SIP/WB002-00000017 is ringing
-- SIP/WB002-00000017 is ringing
-- SIP/WB002-00000017 answered SIP/WB001-00000016
-- Channel SIP/WB002-00000017 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <87c7a794-f9e6-4488-8957-9c0db9e0234f>
-- Channel SIP/WB001-00000016 joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <87c7a794-f9e6-4488-8957-9c0db9e0234f>
[Apr 16 15:32:14] WARNING[13228]: chan_sip.c:4119 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 49e7b55c4a45-rd1is68l1q0a for seqno 2 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 32000ms with no response
 [Apr 16 15:32:14] WARNING[13228]: chan_sip.c:4143 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call 49e7b55c4a45-rd1is68l1q0a - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
-- Channel SIP/WB001-00000016 left 'native_rtp' basic-bridge <87c7a794-f9e6-4488-8957-9c0db9e0234f>
  == Spawn extension (LocalSets, 101, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/WB001-00000016'
-- Channel SIP/WB002-00000017 left 'native_rtp' basic-bridge <87c7a794-f9e6-4488-8957-9c0db9e0234f>
[Apr 16 15:32:14] WARNING[13228][C-00000011]: chan_sip.c:24312 handle_response_invite: Re-invite to non-existing call leg on other UA. SIP dialog '3ca4381a658c7f5f2cee3d8c02acb2a7@172.31.29.187:5060'. Giving up.
```

Comment: This is not a programming question, so is off-topic for SO. You might have better luck at [su] or possibly [sf].

Comment: I took it as a configuration question, most likely my config or exchange.conf settings, sure someone would have experienced the same,  but thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else hits this type of issue, it was a codec and firewall issue, once opened up the RTP ports on the server ( At the EC2 instance in the incomming ensure TCP and UDP match the RTP start and end points in RTP.conf)

In asterisk CLI set your verbosity up to 3 or more and start SIP debugging ( you can do this in the config.conf or at the CLI )

I returned the following on the call

```
== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
-- Executing [200@LocalSets:1] Answer("SIP/WB001-00000000", "") in new stack
-- Executing [200@LocalSets:2] Playback("SIP/WB001-00000000", "hello-world") in new stack
[Apr 18 12:32:02] WARNING[3055][C-00000001]: channel.c:5579 set_format: Unable to find a codec translation path: (gsm) -> (g729)
[Apr 18 12:32:02] WARNING[3055][C-00000001]: file.c:1252 ast_streamfile: Unable to open hello-world (format (g729)): No such file or directory
[Apr 18 12:32:02] WARNING[3055][C-00000001]: app_playback.c:492 playback_exec: Playback failed on SIP/WB001-00000000 for hello-world
-- Executing [200@LocalSets:3] Hangup("SIP/WB001-00000000", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (LocalSets, 200, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/WB001-00000000'
[Apr 18 12:32:34] WARNING[1334]: chan_sip.c:4119 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 3160b85c0cbe-bx3kp12qqxec for seqno 2 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
```

Packet timed out after 32001ms with no response

the issue is that the new installation I didint get a G729 licence so no codec installed, I simply diss-allowed this codec in the sip.conf file.